# How to list multiple rows within Table component specific column?

Tags: jasper-reports

I have Table and I want to display multiple row in same band like the below image

[image]

I have tried with by Adding frame inside the table column and using list component to list multiple rows but it wont works.
like the following hierarchy

```
 Table-->Detail band-->Column-->Frame-->list component-->TextField
```

Can any one help me How to Solve this ? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of doing it.

Way 1:
Put a sub report into last column. Pass the data to it. This way there would be multiple fields in it.

Way 2:
Use groups and custom styles along with groups(styles and groups will have to manages logically).

I think you should go for way 1 if the data in your last column does not span more than one page. Otherwise way 2 is applicable.